# how to install the postgis extension .... despite everything

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-extensions

here is my problem:

I use a PC (with "user" rights) on which the postgresql software is installed (without postgis).

I can't download postgis via stackbuilder (port 443 closed) and I can't work on c:/program files.
In short, I cannot create the postgis extension locally with the command `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`.
On the other hand, I can connect to a remote server equipped with postgresql and various extensions including postgis.

Is there a way to install the postgis extension "locally" under these conditions?

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Comment: You absolutely have to be able to write to the directory where PostgreSQL is installed if you want to install PostGIS.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe thank you